# Ajax data collect in code lines

Tags: ajax

I did some admin panel in wordpress sheet but i'm adding options and have everything in one line in the data, it's pain if I keep adding options, works that way but it looks messy.
example

```
$.ajax({ 
     type: 'POST', 
     url: ajaxurl, 
     data: 'action=general_settings_action&zkr_logo='+zkrlogo+'&zkr_favicon='+zkrfavicon+'&zkr_background='+zkrbackground+'&zkr_linkcolor='+zkrlinkcolor+'&zkr_linkhover='+zkrlinkhover+'&zkr_colorbackground='+zkrcolorbackground,
     success: function(data){
     alert(data);
}});
```

I would like to make some lines to that data field like for example

```
$.ajax({ 
     type: 'POST', 
     url: ajaxurl, 
     data:
          'action=general_settings_action&
          zkr_logo='+zkrlogo+'&
          zkr_favicon='+zkrfavicon+'&
          zkr_background='+zkrbackground+'&
          zkr_linkcolor='+zkrlinkcolor+'&
          zkr_linkhover='+zkrlinkhover+'&
          zkr_colorbackground='+zkrcolorbackground,
     success: function(data){
     alert(data);
}});
```

But putting the code like that doesn't work I have tried with \n and some other stuff but still wont do the work.

I apreciate the help... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:
Make a JSON data object that contains the parameters you want to send

```
var DATA = {
          action:'general_settings_action',
          zkr_logo:zkrlogo,
          zkr_favicon:zkrfavicon,
          zkr_background:zkrbackground,
          zkr_linkcolor:zkrlinkcolor,
          zkr_linkhover:zkrlinkhover,
          zkr_colorbackground:zkrcolorbackground
}
```

The send the data in your AJAX request using the data field

```
$.ajax({ 
     type: 'POST', 
     url: ajaxurl, 
     data: DATA,
     success: function(data){
     alert(data);
}});
```

Comment: Dammmmm thank you very much... in 4 min i'll acept the answer, the page wont let me earlier.... :D!!

Answer (score 0):

I checked this out at: [David Walsh's guide](http://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings)

You need to add

```
'zkr_logo=' + zkrlogo + '' +
```

instead of

```
zkr_logo='+zkrlogo+'&
```

then it will form one String